# How to store a connection string provided by the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a MVC site that connects to some databases to get some views of data.

In this case, is the user who provides the connection string(server,db_name,password) at login, Then I have to pass that connections to the DbContext constructor to perform db operations.

This connections can change in the time so, I can´t set it "fixed" in the WebConfig connection strings section.

Where is the best way to store that connections while the user is loged in?

Comment: Is it considered acceptable to require the user to type in the connection string again every time they log in?

Comment: Store it in the Session object if you just want it to live as long as the user session is alive

Comment: You could extend the applicationUser class and add store them there. You could then retrieve them when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I would save it to a [session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) as @Yacoub suggested.

Comment: My question is more about where to keep the username/password stored to use them every time I call the DBContext constructor?.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it at first. Anyway, I just changed the answer.